# Replace string in each xml file in directory

Tags: linux, unix

How to replace the string “VWAP” with “TWAP” in each xml file in current directory, from the command line?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not related to programming. It is about Linux/Unix and as such should be asked on http://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for i in `ls *.xml`
do
sed -i 's/VWAP/TWAP/g' "$i"
done
IFS=$BIFS
```

Edited after inputs from [Mark Setchell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2836621/mark-setchell), thanks.

Comment: You really shouldn't parse the output of "ls", it causes errors when filenames have spaces and newlines. Just use "for i in *.xml". Likewise, you should double-quote the "$i" at the end of the "sed" command.

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name '*.xml -print -exec sed -i.bak 's/VWAP/TWAP/g' {} \;
```

Comment: You should add a dot (.) after the "find" to give the current directory as the starting point for the search.